# C++ headers inclusion order, strange behaviour

Tags: c++, include, conditional-compilation

I'm writing some library and want to have some "optional" class methods (or just functions), declared or not, dependent on other library inclusion.

Say, I have a class `SomeClass` with method `int foo(std::string)`. Sometimes it's very useful to also have similar method(s) which uses classes of another library the project is build upon - for example, `sf::String` or `wxString`, for SFML or wxWidgets accordingly.

In this case including `SFML/System.hpp` or even worse, `wx/app.hpp` or similar is absolutely **NOT** an option, because I want to have only methods for libraries that are **already** included.  So, my first example must (as I suppose) work fine, but it's not:

main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>       // FIRST, I include SFML base lib in the very first line.
#include <SFML/System/String.hpp>// to be 100% sure, I include SFML string class,
#include "a.h"                   // and ONLY AFTER that I include my own lib
// so inside the "a.h" file, the sf::String class *must* be already declared
main()
{   SomeClass x;
    x.foo("ABC");// error here: "undefined reference to `SomeClass::foo(sf::String)"
}
```

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED
class SomeClass
{   public:
    #ifdef SFML_STRING_HPP
    int foo(sf::String str);// this method is declared, as expected
    #endif
};
#endif
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#ifdef SFML_STRING_HPP
int SomeClass::foo(sf::String str)
{   return 1;
}
#endif
```

**The first question is**: **WHY**? `a.cpp` includes `a.h` in the very beginning, and inside `a.h` the `sf::String` **is** declared, so why inside `a.cpp` **after** `#include "a.h"` it **is not declared** in fact?

I've tried to add `#error OK` right before `#endif` directive in `a.cpp` file, and this error is **not** fired.

Do I miss something about `#include` and `.cpp` / `.h` files?..

**The second question is**: How to fix that or work it around?

(And yes, I do a clean rebuild every time to avoid possible compiler bugs about partially changes sources, g++ likes it).

P.S: The same kind of "dependent" methods declarations works perfectly well with some template class - I suppose, it's because the implementation is within `.h` file where everything is OK about conditional compilation.

Comment: A little hint: You can make `#include` statements also optional by putting them in preprocessor `#ifdef` scopes. So you can include the string header on the same condition as you declare and define the function that uses it.

Comment: Class definitions that change depending on context will bite you sooner or later. Don't do that.

Comment: Pete, why it will bite? I declare and define **different** methods, so in SFML-based project I'll use `fooSM(sf::String)`, in wxWidgets-based project I'll use `fooWX(wxString)` method. This allows me to keep the main library code the same for many different projects, and also avoid excess types conversion (use native types depending on project's base libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.c includes a.h that does not include <SFML/System/String.hpp>, thus SFML_STRING_HPP is not defined. Usually, what to include is set through compiler -D options. For example -DUSE_SFML_STRING

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>       // FIRST, I include SFML base lib in the very first line.
#include "a.h"                   // and ONLY AFTER that I include my own lib
// so inside the "a.h" file, the sf::String class *must* be already declared
main()
{   SomeClass x;
    x.foo("ABC");// error here: "undefined reference to `SomeClass::foo(sf::String)"
}
```

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED

#ifdef USE_SFML_STRING
#include <SFML/System/String.hpp>
#endif

class SomeClass
{   public:
    #ifdef SFML_STRING_HPP
    int foo(sf::String str);// this method is declared, as expected
    #endif
};
#endif
```

Comment: At first I thought everything is compiled starting from main.cpp and including what's necessary, but it is not. Adding project-wide define solves my problem completely. Thanks!